# How to display nothing when resource fails to load from the API in mustache in the context of vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, mustache

I'm new to Vue, so I want to know how to display a blank screen when the resource fails to load from the API. So below is the mustache that I have used in my program, wherein the variable is from the API.

```html
<p class="text-2xl text-success">
    {{'+' + avgSwing.overall_performance + '%'}}%
</p>
```

So when the resource loads from the API, the output obtained is:

```
+36.14%
```

when the resource fails to load from the API, the output obtained is:

```
+undefined%
```

So, I'm expecting a blank screen instead of `+undefined%`, please help me with this.  Thank you.

Comment: What the exact HTML output you wanna to achieve?

Comment: I am actually binding data from the API so I want the symbols to be displayed only when the data is rendering out from the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`v-if`](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) to conditionally show the `<p>` only when there is a response from the API:

```html
<p class="text-2xl text-success" v-if="avgSwing">
   {{ '+' + avgSwing.overall_performance + '%' }}
</p>
```

If `avgSwing` is not defined, the `<p>` tag is not added to the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

The code you've posted, `{{'+' + avgSwing.overall_performance + '%'}}`, will certainly work as long as `avgSwing.overall_performance` is defined. Check the console output, there has to be some kind of error if you don't see the output surrounded by **+** and **%**.

The mustache syntax accepts any valid JavaScript expressions with only certain [limitations](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html).

Comment: Of course the code works, the variable that i have used is from the API, where in I get the desired output only when the recourses are loaded from the API, but when the resources fail to load from the API, I'm getting "+undefined%" ,but I'm expecting a 'blank' instead of that.
So please tell me how it can be done